# What is the way to separate range and pass the array to the function?

Tags: python

I have array of `attachmentList` and

if I do

```
len(attachmentList)
```

the result is 199930; 
and I would like to send 999 elements each time to  api_request(attachment) function

so pseudo code will be like this

```
count=0
for (i=0,i<len(attachmentList),i++)
     count++
     if count=999:
       api_request(attachmentList[i-999:i])
       count=0
```

What is the way to write for loop or there is another solution for that.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: You want to "paginate" the list.  See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950079/paging-python-lists-in-slices-of-4-items

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`grouper` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

And then:

```
for chunk in grouper(attachmentList, 1000):
    api_request(chunk)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop in chunks of 999:

```
for i in range(0, len(attachmentList), 999):
    api_request(attachmentList[i:i+999])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range(...)` function as:

```
previous = 0
for i in range(999,len(attachmentList),999):
    api_request(attachmentList[previous:i]
    previous = i
```